# numpy savetxt gives mismatch error

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm trying to save this array to a csv file using numpy, but I don't understand what the error means, and I can't find answers that work for me on the internet.
What am I missing?

```
x
array([['wisD', 'netl', 'stu', '', 'entl'],
   ['maat', 'wisD', 'stu', '', ''],
   ['lo', 'nat', 'stu', 'schk', 'maat'],
   ['nat', 'fatl', 'stu', 'wisB', 'netl'],
   ['fatl', 'wisB', 'stu', 'wisB', 'ges'],
   ['schk', 'entl', 'stu', 'ges', ''],
   ['wisB', '', 'stu', 'nat', 'AK'],
   ['AK', '', '', '', 'AK'],
   ['', '', '', '', '']], 
  dtype='<U4')
```

The following is the error:

```
 np.savetxt("test.csv", x, delimiter=",")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michiel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1158, in savetxt
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: a float is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    np.savetxt("test.csv", x, delimiter=",")
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1162, in savetxt
% (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U4') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')
```

Comment: @Kasramvd My question can be a duplicate, but I don't understand the answer. On top of that, it doesn't even work for me. Would you mind having a look at this nonetheless?

Comment: You should use `fmt` argument for specifying the format of items. `np.savetxt("test.csv", x, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')`

Comment: It works, thank you!